# Circle-type changing the radius when using font size in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, circletype

I am using Circle-type (https://circletype.labwire.ca/) for text round which is working for the desktop but in the mobile device first it's displayed with default font size and when I refresh the browser then it's talking my actual font size.

For example: If I check first time in mobile it's displaying the default font size. If I refresh the browser then it'd to display the actual font size.

If I set the font size in media query then it's changing the radius also the text.

Desktop
[image]

Default font size

[image]

When I refresh the browser

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  new CircleType(document.getElementById('header_text_round'))
    .radius(220);
});
```

```css
  body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.header_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header_section {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

.banner_bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header_bg {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}

.header_box_wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  right: 15%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media all and (max-width:768px) {
  .mob_header_bg {
    background-image: url("https://lh4.ggpht.com/PbWVvAUJyNT_joymCCwbJCVwvM6JoyV2ogoqhhMT9ZDt4zPjff2Dn0jO8aMDPauwTh4=h900")!important;
  }
  h2#header_text_round {
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 22px !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  body .header_box_wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 20%;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header_wrapper">
  <div class="header_section">
    <div class="header_bg banner_bg mob_header_bg"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header_box_wrapper">
        <div class="header_box">
          <h2 id="header_text_round">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://circletype.labwire.ca/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @UllasHunka, Can you tell me what tool you are using to remove the space from code?

Comment: When you use a snippet, there is a button called tidy on the left-hand side menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any idea of my resolution?

Comment: Sorry, a mistakenly posted wrong answer.

Comment: is your media query closed properly?

Comment: @AravindS, Yes, I forgot to add "}" at the end in the question

Comment: an if you want css for mobile alone means update your code like `@media only screen and (max-width:768px)`

Comment: @AravindS, I added the "}" in the media query

Comment: @user9437856 can you update the media query also as mentioned above?

Comment: @AravindS, I already added the media query in the CSS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176543/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-user9437856).

Comment: If I change the font size in mobile then it's also changing the radius. Might be this is the issue.

Comment: @AravindS, have you checked my issue?

Comment: @user9437856 please check the discussion thread

Answer (score 0):

One fix which you can try is update you font-size in `vw`. i Checked this from resolution 320px an it looks fine upto 767px in both landscape and portrait. So update the CSS like below and let me know

```
h2#header_text_round {
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 5vw !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  new CircleType(document.getElementById('header_text_round'))
    .radius(220);
});
```

```css
  body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.header_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header_section {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

.banner_bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header_bg {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}

.header_box_wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  right: 15%;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media all and (max-width:768px) {
  .mob_header_bg {
    background-image: url("https://lh4.ggpht.com/PbWVvAUJyNT_joymCCwbJCVwvM6JoyV2ogoqhhMT9ZDt4zPjff2Dn0jO8aMDPauwTh4=h900")!important;
  }
  h2#header_text_round {
    color: red !important;
    font-size: 5vw !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  body .header_box_wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 20%;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header_wrapper">
  <div class="header_section">
    <div class="header_bg banner_bg mob_header_bg"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header_box_wrapper">
        <div class="header_box">
          <h2 id="header_text_round">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://circletype.labwire.ca/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's changing the radius in the mobile

Comment: What radius are you for in mobile? You have to adjust the font size in vw according to the radius you needed

Comment: I haven't set the radius for a mobile device. It will take from the plugin but if I am changing the font size then it's changing the radius as well. You can check in your code in the browser.

Comment: I am not sure what radius you are looking for ..since we use vw, it will change based on resolution..so the radius too

Comment: I added the script in the page to display th e-text incurved. and the radius is 220, If I change the font size then it also changes the curved radius. $(document).ready(function() {
        new CircleType(document.getElementById('header_text_round'))
            .radius(220);

    });

Comment: As I believe radius will change based on the font size you apply.so fix a radius which will looks like your mock and adjust the font size..I guess this is what I can help you..

Comment: Thanks for the help, Yes, I am also agreed that it will change the radius if we set any font size but when I am checking website first time than it's displaying the default and after refreshing the browser then it's talking the actual font. I think I have to use another plugin or any css for this issue.

Comment: If my solution helped you really, then upvote and accept. Thanks!